# Is it possible to include a hyperlink in a non-html (outlook) email on python?

Tags: python, email, outlook, hyperlink, format

I am trying to send emails from outlook using a python script. If I do something like this:

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'recipient@outlook.com'
mail.Subject = 'Python test'
mail.Body = 'This is the bodyyyy'
mail.send()
```

Everything runs smooth and the recipient gets the email.
The problem comes when I try to either format the text (bold, underlined,...), include hyperlinks or substitute strings (with `.format()`). I haven't found a way to do that without creating a monster - insane amount of `{{{{asduf}asdf.a()}]]{}}{{})` and so on.

So, is there a way to, in the format I wrote above, send an email including hyperlinks, text formatting and string substitution?

**I haven't found an answer to this specific question and I apologize if it looks too simple for you, I'm just a newbie trying to do newbie stuff.**

Thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the plain text `Body` property, set the `HTMLBody` property to a properly formatted HTML (links and all).

Comment: Omg thanks you are awesome, I've been fighting this for hours and it just worked without creating the monster I was afraid of :___)